# io.sockets.emit works but io.sockets.on doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have to use Socket.IO with ExpressJS route. I am able to emit an event to client but unable to listen to event emitted from client. This issue comes in case  when I have to use socket with Express route.

My `server.js` looks like this: (here `emit` command works but `io.sockets.on` doesn't). I have checked issues with similar problems but still didn't get any clear answer.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = socketio(server);
app.set('socketio', io);
app.post('/deploy', function(request, response) {
  var io = request.app.get('socketio');
  var dapp = "some data";
  io.sockets.emit('deploy', dapp);
  io.sockets.on('deploy_result', (result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`io.sockets.on` (or `io.on`) won't let you listen to all events, it's just for "connection" event. You'll have to attach your listener to each `socket` in order to listen to all events, like this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('deploy_result', (result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
})
```

---

Also it seems like you're trying to get an "acknowledgement" for an `emit`, in which case there already exists a better way - the acknowledgement callback, simply pass a callback method as an additional argument (after the data):

- **`server.js`**

  ```
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('deploy', {some: 'data'}, function acknowledgement_callback (result) {
      console.log(result)
    })
  })
  ```
- **`client.js`**

  ```
  socket.on('deploy', (data, acknowledgement_callback) => {
    // Do something with `data`
    // Then call the callback with any result:
    acknowledgement_callback('result')
    // This will fire the "acknowledgement_callback" above on server-side
  })
  ```

Comment: Infact i have done the same for emit/listen connection events outside express route. Now, i have to send data (from inside app.post request) to client and get back some acknowledgement. Under this express route, socket.emit and socket.on syntax doesn't work, because socket connection lies outside the route and i have used another instance of io by doing ( app.set('socketio', io); var io = request.app.get('socketio') ) to use io.sockets.emit inside specific route. Would you like to tell whats the appropriate way to emit and listen to sockets when they lie inside express post requests.

Comment: You shouldn't be handling Socket.IO from inside an ExpressJS route to begin with. Separate your Socket.IO communication from Express routes entirely. See this example: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ Scroll down to "Integrating Socket.IO", see how socket communications is separate from routes

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install express and socket.io eg. in the directory where you have your files as you can see in your codes and then reference those links appropriately

I have updated your code so issue of express and socket will work. its now left for you to ensure that your application run as you like.
here is the link on how to install express
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

```
var socket  = require( './socket.io' );
var express=require('./express');
var app=express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.post('/deploy', function(request, response) {
  var io = request.app.get('socketio');
  var dapp="some data";
  io.sockets.emit('deploy',dapp);
  io.sockets.on('deploy_result', (result)=>{
    console.log(result);
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi @chinazaike thanks for your time and assistance. But i already have express and socket-io installed and they work correctly outside express routes. My question was for scenario when we have to emit and listen socket events inside routes. In that case, the io.sockets.emit works and i can listen on client side but not the other way.